# string updating in c

Tags: c, string

this is a sample program demonstrating getting a string value from a func

1. can allocate memory inside called function itself and return
2. can allocate memory inside calling function and called function just updates it.

i am facing problem with the 2nd way.
is there any workaround?

```
/*
 * main.c
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 6, 2014
 *      Author: Murtaza
 */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
char* someFunc1();
void someFunc2(char* str);
void firstApproach();
void secondApproach();
int main()
{
    firstApproach();
    printf("\n");
    secondApproach();
    return 0;
}
char* someFunc1()
{
    char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    str = "HELLO";
    return str;
}
void someFunc2(char* str)
{
    str = "Hello";
}
void secondApproach()
{
    char *str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
    someFunc2(str);
    printf(str);
    printf("heythere");
}
void firstApproach()
{
    char *str;
    str=someFunc1();
    printf(str);
    printf("wassup");
}
```

Please tell me why the second approach isn't working.
thanks!
my output is:

```
HELLOwassup
h>heythere
```

and my expected output should be

```
HELLOwassup
Helloheythere
```

Comment: This isn't correct way of copying string: `str="Hello";` Use `strncpy` or `memcpy`.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild: `strncpy()`, despite its name, was not designed to work on strings: it was designed to work on char arrays which do not necessarily have a `'\0'` element.

Comment: @pmg-But,fortunately or unfortunately it does work!

Comment: But, I simply don't understand, why on earth someone would try to do `strncpy` in that way.

Comment: @pmg But nothing prevents one from using strncpy correctly by adding sentinel if that's desired. C was designed to write Unix yet used in all sorts of ways.

Comment: @pmg: I know that, but `strncpy` is a safer option in case you forget to add `\0` at the end of string.

Comment: If you have a `char` array with no `'\0'`, you do not have a string. You cannot use that array with `printf()`, `strlen()`, `strtol()`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at `someFunc2`:

```
void someFunc2(char* str)
{
    /* str is a copy of the pointer that was passed in from secondApproach(). */
    str = "Hello";
}
```

Here, you are passing a pointer by value. Thus, `str` in `someFunc2` is a copy of the original pointer `str` that was passed in from `secondApproach()`. `someFunc2` tells the copy pointer to point somewhere else, but it leaves the original `str` pointer alone. The solution is to pass in the address of the `str` pointer then tell `someFunc2` to modify the pointer at that address to point to `"hello"`.

```
void secondApproach()       
{   
    char* str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);   
    someFunc2(&str); // Pass in the address of str.
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("heythere");
}

void someFunc2(char** str)
{
    *str = "hello";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void someFunc2(char* str)  
{ 
    str="Hello";   //-----the variable str is local to this function, thus it goes out of scope as
                   // soon as the function returns  
}  
void secondApproach()  
{
    char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);   
    someFunc2(str);  
    printf(str);  // -------------- here the value inside str is some garbage value.    
    printf("heythere");    
} 

CORRECTION :   



void someFunc2(char **str )     
    {
       *str = "hello";     
    }     

void secondApproach()       
{   
   char *str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);   
        someFunc2(&str);    // pass the address of the string      
        printf("%s", str);          
        printf("heythere");     
}
```

Comment: that explained a lot of things, i never really understood the pointers to pointers concept except in 2d arrays. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you write a string between quotes and use it directly as:

- a char* -> it gets created in a mutable place in memory, and gives its address to the pointer variable its assigned to. It is still in memory as long as that variable referencing it is not NULL.
- an argument -> it gets created as `char*` and passed to the function (and treated there as a char*), then automatically disposed from memory (i.e. you can't access it or reference it anymore) ..

So, the only situation when a string is actually mutable is when you assign it to a `char[]`, then it gets created in readonly memory and copied into to the stack .. ( the copy on the stack is what the `char[]` variable will point to )

If you think about it for some time, you realize that this is one of the benefits of dynamic memory: you can create a `char*` that **is** mutable, and since it is just a pointer, you don't need to specify the size of the string it is going to point at. So you can see how useful this would be ..

Also, it's worth to note that in functions:

- if you pass a string, the variable in the function itself is treated as a char pointer and most likely would try to modify it, and if it's readonly that would raise a Segmentation Fault. So functions are assuming you know what you're doing ..
- if you want a function to be able to modify a string directly (i.e string = "somestring") then pass it a pointer to the actual string, else the modification will only be local to the function. That's because the string is a "pointer to char", so the function can't modify the string as a whole. But that also means that a function can modify the string's characters individually ( obviously, because it has a pointer for characters: the string ). If you pass it, however, a string pointer (`char**`), the function can modify the string directly (`*string = "whatever"`) and can also modify the characters individually (`*string[1] = 'C'`). Which choice you need depends entirely on the purpose of the function ..

Now, for your specific example, you can do one of two ..

#### Using a pointer to a pointer to a char (string pointer)

```
void someFunc2(char** str)
{
    *str = "Hello";
}
```

#### Using a pointer to char (string)

```
void someFunc2(char* str)
{
    char *k = "Hello";
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        str[i] = k[i];
}
```

This is one of the most controversial and advanced topics in C. No matter what type of C programming you're doing, you have to understand these core concepts ..